# Rails says it cannot find jquery.ui.sortable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-4

Gemfile (I have run bundle `install` and `bundle update`):

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.ui.sortable
//= require_tree .
```

my_stylesheet.css:

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.sortable
 */
```

---

When I reload the webpage Rails is giving me the following error message:

```
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.sortable'
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error is because jquery-ui doesn't include a stylesheet for sortable. Remove *= require jquery.ui.sortable from your stylesheet and reload.